# How to get a list using neo4j python driver?

Tags: python, neo4j, driver

When my query asks for a single response everything is OK, but when I try to get a whole list, it gives my this error:

Record name=u'Tom Hanks' relations=12>
/home/roldanx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/api.py:772: UserWarning: Expected a result with a single record, but this result contains 13

Which only gives me the first row of the list (Tom Hanks, 12). Is there any way I can get the whole list? This is my code:

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase

    driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "password"))

    session = driver.session()

    def degree():
        return session.run("""
            MATCH(a:Person{name:"Tom Hanks"})--(b)
            return a.name AS name, count(distinct b) AS relations
            UNION 
            MATCH (a:Person{name:"Tom Hanks"})--(b)--(c)
            return b.title AS name, (count(distinct c)+1) AS relations
            """)

    deg = degree().single()
    print(deg)
    driver.close()
```

Comment: In ``degree().single()`` don't you specifically take a single element from the result?

Comment: Yes I do. I need to know which other method should I use. I couldn't find it in the official manual nor in the other websites. The problem I'm finding with this python driver is that very few people use it so it's hard to solve even simple problems like this one.

Comment: Yes it did. Lot of thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a cypher query, a BoltStatementResult is returned. It provides a handle to the result of the query, but also some metadata. So you can't directly typecast it into a list. But it is iterable, so you can simply loop over the result to get all the records:

```
result = degree()
entire_result = [] # Will contain all the items
for record in result:
    entire_result.append(record)
```